# Find Jacobian of $x^2 -y^2$

Tags: matrices

I am struggling with this one, although I expect there to be a simple solution that I just can't seem to find.

$$f(x, y) = x^2 - y^2$$

"Find the Jacobian of $f(x, y)$ at the point $(1, 1)$. Give a geometric interpretation of the Jacobian at this point. "

Previously I have only encountered problems one the form $g(x, y) = (ax^2 + by, cx -y^2)$ or similarly, so I have no idea how to approach a problem with only one function.

Comment: yes, but I wouldn't think this deserves a -3, it's not so standard to call it so.

Comment: @Surb: you means of a **scalar** field ?

Comment: You could pretend you consider the function $f(x,y)= (x^2 - y^2, 0)$.

Comment: Thanks guys! I tried your tip earlier today quid, but then I'll end up with determinant equal to zero?

Comment: @quid: You are surely joking, aren't you!

Comment: @AlexM. If OP really knows how to deal with functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ they really could do the calculation for that function. Then I assume they will note how to solve their original problem.  Of course as a general method it would be non-sensical to proceed like this. But to clear up the specific issue it might have helped. But I should have added a further explanation on the nature of my advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are required to find the Jacobian matrix, i.e. the matrix filled with the 1st order partial derivatives of $f$, not to find the determinant of this matrix.

If I am right, then the Jacobian matrix at $(1,1)$ is $\left( \frac {\partial f} {\partial x}, \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} \right) (1,1) = (2x, -2y) (1,1) = (2, -2)$.

The geometrical interpretation is the following: the graph of $f = 0$ without the origin $(0,0)$ is a thing called "differentiable manifold" of dimension $1$. The numbers $2$ and $-2$ obtained above are the parameters of the tangent line at this manifold at the point $(1,1)$; more precisely, the tangent line at the manifold in this point has the equation $2x - 2y = 0$.

Comment: Maybe add that this object is usually called the *gradient* of the function.